# Disable ajax add to cart on first item and custom redirect it on Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

Hi I am working on a WOOCOMMERCE site and
I am trying to redirect user to a custom page when the user tries to add his first product into the cart.

The redirection should be done only for the first product in the cart.

When the user adds two or more products in the cart then the normal ajax add to cart should function.

Firstly I tried redirecting to custom page for the first product by using the function below

```
function my_custom_add_to_cart_redirect( $url ) {  
    if (WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 0)
    $url = get_permalink( 1172 ); /* ID of the page is entered */
    return $url;
    }
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'my_custom_add_to_cart_redirect' );
```

The above code does redirect to custom page but it happens for all product additions to cart.

Moreover it does not work when "Redirect to the cart page after successful addition" field is unchecked in WOOCommerce Settings.

Can anyone help me with the right approach ?

Answer (score 0):

You need some additional code to disable add to cart when cart is empty and to change a bit your code:

```
// Replacing the ajax add to cart button by a link to the product when cart is empty
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replace_loop_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function replace_loop_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product  ) {
    if( WC()->cart->is_empty() && $product->is_type('simple') ){
        $button_text = __( "View product", "woocommerce" );
        $button = '<a class="button product_type_simple" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';
    }
    return $button;
}

// Custom Redirect on first added to cart only
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'custom_add_to_cart_redirect_on_first_item' );
function custom_add_to_cart_redirect_on_first_item( $url ) {
    // Redirect on first added item
    if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 1 ) {
        return get_permalink( 1172 ); // ID of the page
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your answer. But my question was only the first product add to cart should redirect to custom page and the remaining should be ajax add to cart.

Comment: @RameshRamGopal Yes that is what this code do… so you need to remove settings as "redirect to cart on add to cart", to make it work. This code is tested and works perfectly.

Comment: Hi LoicTheAztec, the above code does work but the problem is it opens the product page first before redirecting. This way user will be viewing product and adding to cart. I was trying to achieve the solution without the user having to visit the product page.

Comment: @RameshRamGopal That is not possible as you need to have the ajax add to cart disabled on first add to cart… so no other way than going on the product itself. Also remember that when product is not a simple one, you have anyway to go to the product page.